# What states of matter does not exist naturally on Earth?

Tags: plasma-physics, bose-einstein-condensate, time-crystals

I am already aware that each state (solid, liquid, and gas) naturally occurs on Earth.
But I am not quite sure about Plasma, Time-Crystals, and Bose-Einstein condensate (BEC)

And can time-crystals and Bose-Einstein condensate (BEC) naturally occur in space?

Comment: The Earth's ionosphere is a plasma, and the northern and southern polar lights are plasmas. Plasma is also briefly formed in a lightning bolt.

Comment: Don't forget the type of material found in neutron stars. I think it's called degenerate matter, not sure. Or the stuff in a quark star.

Comment: Don't forget superfluids, whose characteristics are distinct from normal fluids.